# Custom Authorization header leads to missing status code. IIS 10.0

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have a webapplication that isn't returning any status code at all for all requests that have an Authorization request header of the Bearer type.

I have made a small proof of concept with a new site in IIS and just an index.html file.

I have done four requests to this site:
[four request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqDgL.png)

- _t=A is a request without the Authorization header.
- _t=B is a request with the Authorization header set to Bearer
- _t=C is a request with the Authorization header set to Basic
- _t=D is a request with the Authorization header set to Basicc

All four requests have sent the same response it just looks like the status code isn't sent to requests with an Authorization scheme that is unknown to IIS.

In the WS3SVC log file all requests do have a status 200:

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2016-08-19 13:37:41 ::1 GET /index.html _t=A 5443 - ::1 HTTP/2.0 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+rv:47.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/47.0 https://localhost:5443/index.html 200 0 0 4
2016-08-19 13:37:53 ::1 GET /index.html _t=B 5443 - ::1 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+rv:47.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/47.0 https://localhost:5443/index.html 200 0 0 1
2016-08-19 13:38:05 ::1 GET /index.html _t=C 5443 - ::1 HTTP/2.0 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+rv:47.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/47.0 https://localhost:5443/index.html 200 0 0 3
2016-08-19 13:38:14 ::1 GET /index.html _t=D 5443 - ::1 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+rv:47.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/47.0 https://localhost:5443/index.html 200 0 0 3
```

I have also tested this on a different machine (also Windows 10 & IIS 10.0) and it has the same behavior.

Although it doesn't break the website by not sending a status code I still think there must be a way to resolve this issue.

Comment: I don't think this is issue with IIS. I have tested it and getting a 200 for custom authorization headers. Looks like it is getting stripped over the wire. Did you try reproducing the issue locally on that server ?

Comment: The results from the image are from my own machine, so they are requests to localhost. But i have also tested going from my machine to a different machine and it displayed the same behavior. But i will try and test it tomorrow locally from the other machine with a different browser.